# Rails Select Tag for Time Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a simple way to show a drop down list for time selection in Rails 4.

I want a select tag inside my for that ranges from 7am to 6pm(like 7 am, 7.30 am, 8 am, 8.30 am...) and the value is to be stored in a column with attribute `TIME`

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour

Comment: Or this one http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select

Comment: @Pavan  how to do the same in a form..
Im using a form and right now i have tag like
f.time_field :appointment_time, class: 'form-control'

What i want is to have a select tag  like 7.00am 7.30am, 8.00am....

Comment: You will find more info in the given links.

Comment: Use `minute_step` option for that.And to get `am` and `pm` use `:ampm => true` `f.time_select :appointment_time, class: 'form-control',{minute_step: 30,:ampm => true}`

Comment: Can you post that code which you tried?

Comment: And also any errors you got?

Comment: how to set start and stop time

Comment: that error comment was for your previous comment

Comment: `select_hour(my_time, start_hour: 2, end_hour: 14)`